# Angular 6 SSR TypeError: Cannot read property 'root' of undefined

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-functions, angular6, server-side-rendering

I have an angular 6.03 project using Angular Universal that is deployed to firebase. Until a few days ago all was working perfectly but last time I deployed I started getting cannot read property 'root' of undefined error.

```
error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'root' of undefined
at new rootRoute (/Users/rebekahapelt/Projects/hapkido-website/functions/node_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js:5390:35)
at _createClass (/Users/rebekahapelt/Projects/hapkido-website/functions/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:8445:24)
at _createProviderInstance (/Users/rebekahapelt/Projects/hapkido-website/functions/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:8417:30)
at initNgModule (/Users/rebekahapelt/Projects/hapkido-website/functions/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:8350:36)
at new NgModuleRef_ (/Users/rebekahapelt/Projects/hapkido-website/functions/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:9076:13)
at Object.createNgModuleRef (/Users/rebekahapelt/Projects/hapkido-website/functions/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:9065:16)
at NgModuleFactory_.create (/Users/rebekahapelt/Projects/hapkido-website/functions/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:11607:29)
at /Users/rebekahapelt/Projects/hapkido-website/functions/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:4375:47
at ZoneDelegate.invoke (/Users/rebekahapelt/Projects/hapkido-website/functions/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js:388:26)
at Object.onInvoke (/Users/rebekahapelt/Projects/hapkido-website/functions/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:3890:37)
```

So I am a little confused and all other questions relating to this seem to be about unit testing.

My server.ts file looks like

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
import * as firebaseFunctions from 'firebase-functions';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import * as express from 'express';

const { AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP} = require('./main');
import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
import { provideModuleMap } from '@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader';

enableProdMode();

const app = express();

app.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
  bootstrap:  AppServerModuleNgFactory,
  providers: [
    provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
  ]
}));

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', __dirname);


app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', {req});
});


exports.ssrApp = firebaseFunctions.https.onRequest(app);
```

My github repo is https://github.com/rapelt/hapkido-website

I am using Angular Material which has caused some interesting and annoying problems with animation but I have had all that fixed for quite a while.

Anyone got any suggestions?

Comment: try to build and deploy once again.

Answer (score 0):

After much thought and trial and error the answer was that Angular animation version 6.0.4 didn't work with the server side application. Down grading to 6.0.3 fixed the problem locally but not as a deployed application. Updating all angular packages, @nguniversal/express-engine and typescript fixed the project.